# Line breaks in custom option textarea

Tags: custom-options, magento-enterprise

I have a **product that has some custom options**, one of them being a **text area.**

We're having an issue where it seems that Magento is getting rid of any leading or trailing line breaks that are entered in that text area.

Is this something that Magento does by defualt and something that I can disable?

Comment: I'm not sure, this is used, but maybe the `trim()` at `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/Text.php:48` in `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_Text::validateUserValue` is your problem.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt why not add this as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, this is used, but maybe the `trim()` at

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/Text.php:48
```

in

```
\Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_Text::validateUserValue
```

is your problem.

Comment: Unless we're talking about good old `nl2br` problem. Question mentions leading and trailing line breaks, but says nothing about line breaks in the middle of textarea.

Comment: I habe no idea what you are talking about, but I don't think nl2br is part of the problem?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: lol :-) No this function I know of course, but what do you mean by "good old nl2br problem"?

Comment: HTML automatically collapses excessive whitespaces, including line breaks. Web designers sometimes forget that and spend lot of time wondering why rum^H^H^Hline breaks are gone.